# Debugging with FirePhp

Tags: php, firephp

I'm familiar with the following syntax for debugging using FirePhp:

```
$this->firephp->log($this->db->queries); // for printing SQL queries
$this->firephp->log($var); // for printing variables
```

I wonder if their are more arguments for the log() method...for debugging?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the manual says?

Comment: Couldn't find anything new so far.

Comment: I would rather check the log class to see available methods